# TypeScript, React - why is ts falling back to any for certain prop type definitions?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following props typing:

```
export interface ITouchable {
  isDisabled?: boolean;
  margin?: Margin;
  height?: number;
  bgColor?: string;
}
```

Where `Margin` is:

```
type Margin =
  | {
      top?: number;
      bottom?: number;
      left?: number;
      right?: number;
    }
  | [number | undefined, number | undefined]
  | number;
```

But when I use my `Touchable`, `margin` is set to `any`:

```
<Touchable margin="foo" /> // <-- should cause an error but ITouchable.margin?: any
```

I have no idea why this would happen. In the TypeScript playground I am getting the expected behavior. All the other prop definitions are correct:

```
<Touchable bgColor={5} /> // <-- type number is not assignable to string
```

If I import that padding type and declare my type as padding it is fine:

```
import { Padding } from "@types";

const pad: Padding = "foo" // <-- error as expected
```

And if I declare `Padding` in the same file as `ITouchable` it works fine as well. But it seems to me that I should be able to import from my global type definitions and consume them without this problem.

My basic file structure is

```
src ->
  @types ->
    index.ts // <-- Margin is defined here

  components ->
    Touchable.tsx // <-- Touchable, as well as ITouchable is defined here

router.tsx // <-- I'm using Touchable here (in my project root)
```

And some potentially relevant properties from my `tsconfig`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["react-native"],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@components": ["src/components"],
      "@store": ["./src/store"],
      "@store/*": ["./src/store/*"],
      "@utils/*": ["./src/utils/*"],
      "@types": ["./src/@types"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this was happening was because my `router.tsx` was outside of my `./src` directory.

Once I moved `router` to `src` the correct type definitions appeared. I'm certain that the issue was caused by my `baseUrl` and `paths` variables but I'm not sure how exactly.

If someone could explain how I could have fixed this by editing my `tsconfig` (as opposed to changing my project structure) I'll happily mark your answer as correct.